# Mysql Result Based On Foreign Key Table's Column Value

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a php-mysql library as my study project where i can have many tables but have access to control the row of subtable based on the value of maintable

I have two mysql tables

```
Create Table MainTable(
 UID int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARYKEY,
 can_see int(1)
);

Create Table Articles(
 UID int(10),
 title varcha(100)
 FOREIGN KEY (`UID`) REFERENCES `MainTable` (`UID`)
);
```

UID is common in MainTable and Articles Table. I can see an article only when 'can_see' in MainTable is set to '1'.

This is my php code

```
 getTableData($table, $selection = '*', $condition = FALSE) {
  if($condition)
   $condition = 'where '.$condition;
  mysql_query("select $selection from $table $condition");
  // AFTER THIS SOME CODE TO LOOP AND RETURN THE DATA
 }
```

I am able to get the data but problem is i want to get the data only if "article UID" is enabled in "MainTable"

I know i have to use joins and table alias but this is a dynamic query so i'm stuck. I have an ugly solution

```
select $selection from $table where UID in (
 select UID from MainTable where UID in (
  select UID from $table $condition
 )
)
```

I did benchmark and it is taking double amount of time compared to table joins but i'm unable to figure out how i can build a dynamic query for joins. Joins query looks simple like below if we are building it manually

```
select a.title from Articles a, MainTable m where a.UID=m.UID AND m.can_see='1'
```

I hope someone can sort it

Comment: If you want to build given query , You can simply pass parameter table as `Articles a, MainTable m` same way selection and condition

Comment: i wanted to create a function which is handy .. if i send 'Articles a, MainTable m' the syntax become long and confusing

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select a.title 
from Articles a 
join MainTable m on 
a.UID=m.UID 
where m.can_see='1';
```